# What's the best way to implement HTTP Post chunked request on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, http, networking, chunked-encoding

There's a really old thread from 2008 that mentioned NSUrlConnection is quite buggy and leaks a lot. Is this still the case?

Is there any Cocoa Touch class that already implements the chunked upload or am I better off using the CF classes?

Comment: `NSURLConnection` works fine on the whole. Use the highest-level API available, and drop down lower if it starts being a problem.

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection doesn't leak, but you DO need to know when and where to release your references to it. Bear in mind that on a mobile device, streaming upload is a bad plan, because you're keeping the radio on fairly consistently, and probably overriding whatever power management is designed to keep it inactive where possible.

In the mobile space, if it is at all possible to upload the file all at once, I would suggest going that way.